# OpenLayers3 + Cesium add 3D Models

Tags: openlayers, cesium, 3d-model

I created an Openlayers3 Bing map and then I converted to 3D view with Cesium. Is there a way to add a 3D Model on my 3D map?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Cesium has [support for 3D models](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=3D%20Models.html&label=All).  It uses the [glTF file format](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF) to describe the models.

At its simplest, the code looks like this:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var entity = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Test model',
    position : position,
    orientation : orientation,
    model : {
        uri : 'server/path/to/model.gltf'
    }
});
```

(Disclaimer, I'm a Cesium and glTF contributor, but I don't know much about the OL3 integration.  There may be some other recommended way to add the model via OL3, but ultimately it will need to reach the Cesium layer and execute code like I've shown here).

Comment: Thank for your reply emackey. Do you have any idea for this? My code for this part is here:

Comment: var map3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: map});
    var scene = map3d.getCesiumScene();
    var modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
            Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(24.823608, 35.234403, 200.0));
    var model = scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
        url: 'Cesium_Man.gltf',
        modelMatrix: modelMatrix
    }));
    var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url: '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world',
    });
    scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;

Comment: You should edit your original question to add this code with proper formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
var map3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: map});
var scene = map3d.getCesiumScene();
var modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
        Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(24.823608, 35.234403, 200.0));
var model = scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
    url: 'Cesium_Man.gltf',
    modelMatrix: modelMatrix
}));
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
    url: '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world',
});
scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
map3d.setEnabled(true);
```